# How to parallelize subgraph executions in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to increase my GPU utilization in TensorFlow but I find that subgraph executions are not parallelized. 
Here is working example (tensorflow version r.012):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.client import timeline

#initialize graph
tf.reset_default_graph()
sess = tf.Session()

# some parameters
input_dim = 10000
output_dim = 100
num_hidden = 10000
batch_size = 256
```

First we create two networks:

```
#specify two networks with random inputs as data
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    # first network
    with tf.variable_scope('net1'):
        tf_data1 = tf.random_normal(shape=[batch_size, input_dim])
        w1 = tf.get_variable('w1', shape=[input_dim, num_hidden], dtype=tf.float32)
        b1 = tf.get_variable('b1', shape=[num_hidden], dtype=tf.float32)
        l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(tf_data1, w1), b1)
        w2 = tf.get_variable('w2', shape=[num_hidden, output_dim], dtype=tf.float32)
        result1 = tf.matmul(l1, w2)

    # second network
    with tf.variable_scope('net2'):
        tf_data2 = tf.random_normal(shape=[batch_size, input_dim])
        w1 = tf.get_variable('w1', shape=[input_dim, num_hidden], dtype=tf.float32)
        b1 = tf.get_variable('b1', shape=[num_hidden], dtype=tf.float32)
        l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(tf_data1, w1), b1)
        w2 = tf.get_variable('w2', shape=[num_hidden, output_dim], dtype=tf.float32)
        result2 = tf.matmul(l1, w2)
```

This is what we are interested in:

```
    #the result that we are interested
    out = tf.add(result1, result2)
```

Now we initialize and run the session:

```
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) #initialize variables

# run out operation with trace
run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata() 
sess.run(out,
        options=tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE),
        run_metadata=run_metadata )

# write trace to file
trace = timeline.Timeline(step_stats=run_metadata.step_stats)
trace_file = open('trace.ctf.json', 'w')
trace_file.write(trace.generate_chrome_trace_format())
```

In the [trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWsb1.png) we can see the following:

- The first Matmul is for the net1, and the second Matmul is for net2.

**Questions:**

1 - Since the result1 does not depend on result2 why these operations are not processed in parallel when calling the parent operation ''out''?

2- Am I doing something wrong when defining the graph? From the [documentation](https://github.com/petewarden/tensorflow_ios/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/resources/faq.md#does-the-runtime-parallelize-parts-of-graph-execution) I understand that Tensorflow does concurrency automatically.

3- Is there any way  I can achieve concurrency at this level?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Re (1) TensorFlow by default uses a single GPU stream. If you run your code on CPU, you'll see parallelism. To get better GPU utilization it's best to increase your batch size / kernel size instead.

Re (2) your graph seems to be correctly defined. The automatic parallelization mostly applies to the CPU.

Re (3) there is as of 1.0 no way to run multi-compute-stream code on TensorFlow GPU.